# Ansible - using "include" and "include_tasks" modules

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-galaxy

I've downloaded the [docker role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/docker) and when I'm running the role i get the following error:

```
The error appears to have been in '/some_folder/geerlingguy.docker/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- include_tasks: setup-RedHat.yml
  ^ here
```

and when I replace the module `include_task` module with the `include` module everything works as expected.

what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ansible version lower to 2.4 then it can be expected as `include_task` was introduced in Ansible 2.4
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/include_tasks_module.html

Comment: Thanks! that solved this issue - I'm using Ansible 2.2.1.0

Comment: That's great to hear. Feel free to accept the answer if you are happy so that it can be helpful to others as well.